# Require user to accept terms on login

Tags: windows, login, group-policy

You know when you log on to a work or public computer, and they have a user terms agreement that you need to accept in order to use the system? How do I set this up on windows XP and windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7, what you're looking for appears to be in the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system\`

[image: legal notice]

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/02/08/deploying-legal-notices-to-domain-computers-using-group-policy.aspx

This may be different in Windows XP, as I'm seeing on the [references on the web](http://www.theeldergeek.com/create_legal_notice_logon_dialog_box.htm) to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` which don't appear on my Win 7 hive.